# adding a delay on the start of chart.js animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm using the chart.js to display some graphic and I would like to insert a delay before the start of the animation of the Doughnut.

Could anyone please help me about this?

Thanks in advance.
Sylvain

Comment: Hiee sylvain.welcome to stackoverflow. You should provide relevant code for problem you are having

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like anyone posted the answer. In version 3+ it's the following:

```
options: {
  animation: {
    delay: 1000, // change delay to suit your needs.
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install: `chartjs-plugin-deferred` [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-deferred) and then add to your item.

```
{
    plugins: {
        deferred: {           // enabled by default
            xOffset: 150,     // defer until 150px of the canvas width are inside the viewport
            yOffset: '50%',   // defer until 50% of the canvas height are inside the viewport
            delay: 500        // delay of 500 ms after the canvas is considered inside the viewport
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Doughnut Chart</title>
    <script src="../Chart.js"></script>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no">

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="450"></canvas>


<script>

    var doughnutData = [
            {
                value: 30,
                color:"#F7464A"
            },
            {
                value : 50,
                color : "#46BFBD"
            },
            {
                value : 100,
                color : "#FDB45C"
            },
            {
                value : 40,
                color : "#949FB1"
            },
            {
                value : 120,
                color : "#4D5360"
            }

        ];

    //this part will add 2s delay on page load for chart
    window.onload=function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
        }, 2000);
    };

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: That does not delay the animation, it delays the instantiation of the chart.